# Improper multiple integals involving inner porduct

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following expression: 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \langle x,a \rangle^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lvert x \rvert^2}dx$$
where $x,a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried reduction to the case where $a$ is an element of the "natural basis" in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I can't see how to go from there.

Comment: Did you try to use Spherical coordinates?

Comment: Yes, in 3 dimensions. but in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I'm not sure how to do the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : I know I forgot the square in this proof, but please read the proof without the square, as the approach with the square is very analogous.

Write $\langle x,a \rangle = a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n$ and $|x|^2 = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$, so that $e^{-|x|^2} = e^{-x_1^2} \cdots e^{-x_n^2}$. By Fubini's theorem, your integral becomes
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}\langle x,a \rangle e^{-|x|^2} dx = \sum_{i=1}^n  \int_{\mathbb R^n} a_i x_i e^{-|x|^2} \, dx_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \left( \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x^2} \, dx \right)^{n-1} \int_{\mathbb R} x_i e^{-x_i^2} \, dx_i. 
$$
The power to the $n-1$ appears because the integrals $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x_j^2} \, dx_j$ do not depend on $j$ for $1 \le j \le n$, $j \neq i$. These integrals correspond to the error function, so their value is well-known ; by integration by parts you can do the last integral with respect to $x_i$. I leave the computations to you.

Now if you want to do it with the square, do the exact same trick ; the integrals appearing are just a bit more complicated (the integral of $x^2 e^{-x^2}$ instead of $xe^{-x^2}$) and there are a bit more terms. Fubini's theorem splits the product of variables appearing when you square the inner product. The error function $\mathrm{erf}(x_i)$ should show up in the computations.

Added : As suggested by the OP in the comments, let $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be an orthogonal transformation with $Ta = (|a|,0,\cdots,0)$. Since the Jacobian is $1$, letting $u = Tx$, because $|u| = |Tx| = |x|$, this integral becomes
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} \langle x,a \rangle^2 e^{-|x|^2} \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \langle Tx,Ta \rangle^2 e^{-|x|^2} \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \langle u,Ta \rangle^2 e^{-|u|^2} \, du = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |a|^2u_1^2 e^{-|u|^2} \, du. 
$$
Now use Fubini and complete as in my other example. But as I said above, you still need to integrate $\int_{\mathbb R} x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx$ in any case ; with the hint you only spare yourself the sums and re-arranging.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Did you mean $-{x_i}^2$ where you switched sum and integral? (Instead of $-|x|^2$ )

Comment: @UriaMor : No, I meant what is written there, i.e. $-|x|^2$. Note that $(a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n) e^{-|x|^2} = a_1 x_1 e^{-|x|^2} + \cdots + a_n x_n e^{-|x|^2}$. There is no mistake =) note that $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x_i^2} \, dx_i$ is just a number (check out the error function's properties to figure out what it is! Or perhaps you recall your statistics course, since this is the function which appears when considering the normal distribution...)

Comment: We received a hint: to use an orthogonal linear map $T \in O(n)$ change variables so that  $Ta = (|a|,0...,0)$. I see how it makes things a lot more clear - do you mind adding this idea to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple. In $\mathbb R^2$ you have
\begin{align*}
\int \langle x,a\rangle^2e^{-|x|^2/2}\,dx
&= \int\int (a_1^2x_1^2+2a_1a_2x_1x_2+a_2^2x_2^2)e^{-x_1^2/2}e^{-x_2^2/2}\,dx_1\,dx_2\\
&= a_1^2\int\left(\int x_1^2e^{-x_1^2/2}\,dx_1\right)e^{-x_2^2/2}\,dx_2 + 2a_1a_2\left(\int xe^{-x^2/2}\,dx\right)^2\\
&\qquad\qquad+ a_2^2\int x_2^2e^{-x_2^2/2}\left(\int e^{-x_1^2/2}\,dx_1\right)dx_2\\
&= 2\pi a_1^2 + 0 + 2\pi a_2^2 = 2\pi(a_1^2+a_2^2)
\end{align*}
In higher dimensions you can proceed analogously. In the end, your result should be $(2\pi)^{n/2}\|a\|_2^2$.